# SAPUI5 change operationMode to client in runtime

Tags: sapui5

I am using SmartTable in my project.

I need to request some data from backend at begin and then work on received data in frontend.

By data, that i need from backend i must send some filter.

So i need at begin the operationMode `Server`, and after data come change it to `Client`

My SmartTable xml

```xml
<smartTable:SmartTable id="ReportSmartTable" entitySet="OwnSet"
    tableBindingPath="/OwnSet" tableType="AnalyticalTable"
    beforeRebindTable="onBeforeRebindTable" >
```

onBeforeRebindTable

```js
onBeforeRebindTable: function (oEvent) {
    console.log("onBeforeRebindTable");
    var oBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
    oBindingParams.filters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Prop", "EQ", "Value"));
},
```

in onInit i set listener, to change the operation mode after data receiving

```js
var oTable = this.getView().byId("ReportSmartTable"); //Get Hold of the table control
oTable.attachDataReceived(function (oEvent) { //Hits when the data is received from back-end server
    this.getModel().defaultOperationMode = "Client"; //Set operation mode to Client
    var oSource = oEvent.getSource();
    oSource.bClientOperation = true; //Set Client Operation to true
    oSource.sOperationMode = "Client"; //Set operation mode to Client
}.bind(this));
```

i have also tried to change operationMode by following

```js
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel().sDefaultOperationMode = "Client";
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel().defaultOperationMode = "Client";
this.getModel().sDefaultOperationMode = "Client"; //Set operation mode to Client
this.getModel().defaultOperationMode = "Client"; //Set operation mode to Client
```

but it doesn't work.

If i make some filter after data is received, there still comes request to backend.

By making `Client` operationMode from begin, `onBeforeRebindTable` is called before request, but the filter is not sended with `batch`

Comment: any update on how you solved this issue please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the operation mode after a model is created. Even if you update the **private** attribute `sDefaultOperationMode`, it will not affect existing bindings.

You can specify the `operationMode` per binding, for example in a list:

```
<List items="{path:'/myset',parameters:{operationMode:'Client'}}" ...>
```

and use [`ListBase.bindItems`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase/methods/bindItems) to re-create a binding with a different operation mode.

For a `SmartTable`, however, you'd have to modify the internal table bindings and this would probably break a lot of things, therefore it's discouraged. Maybe the Smart Table is not the best fit for your use case.

Comment: Is there a way to send a filter to backend at initial request in `Client` operationMode?

Comment: I don't think so.